# tf.keras.models.save_model not saving the probabilistic_model

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tf.keras, tensorflow-probability

**System information**

- Have I written custom code (as opposed to using a stock example script provided in TensorFlow): Yes
- OS Platform and Distribution (e.g., Linux Ubuntu 16.04): Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
- TensorFlow installed from (source or binary):binary
- TensorFlow version (use command below): v2.5.0-rc3-213-ga4dfb8d1a71 2.5.0
- Tensorflow_probability.**version**:  '0.13.0'
- Python version: 3.8.10
- CUDA/cuDNN version: cuda_11.2.r11.2/compiler.29373293_0
- GPU model and memory: 12Gb TitanXP

**Describe the current behavior**
Tensorflow model with tensorflow_probability layers creates errors while saving

** The model is created using the below code**

```
    model = Sequential([
            Conv2D(8, 5, activation='relu', padding='valid', input_shape=input_shape),
            MaxPooling2D(6),
            Flatten(),
            Dense(10),
            tfpl.OneHotCategorical(10)
        ])
        model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=loss, metrics=metrics)
    
    probabilistic_model = get_probabilistic_model(
        input_shape=(28, 28, 1), 
        loss=nll, 
        optimizer=RMSprop(), 
        metrics=['accuracy']
    
    probabilistic_model.fit(x_train, y_train_oh, epochs=5)
```

**For saving the model**

```
    probabilistic_model.save('/tmp/model/probabilistic_model')
```

The saving steps create the error as shown below.

```
OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError            Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_11377/1109926494.py in <module>
----> 1 probabilistic_model.save('/tmp/model/probabilistic_model')
~/tf2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in save(self, filepath, overwrite, include_optimizer, save_format, signatures, options, save_traces)
   2109     """
   2110     # pylint: enable=line-too-long
-> 2111     save.save_model(self, filepath, overwrite, include_optimizer, save_format,
   2112                     signatures, options, save_traces)
   2113 
~/tf2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/save.py in save_model(model, filepath, overwrite, include_optimizer, save_format, signatures, options, save_traces)
    148   else:
    149     with generic_utils.SharedObjectSavingScope():
--> 150       saved_model_save.save(model, filepath, overwrite, include_optimizer,
    151                             signatures, options, save_traces)
    152 
~/tf2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/save.py in save(model, filepath, overwrite, include_optimizer, signatures, options, save_traces)
     87   with K.deprecated_internal_learning_phase_scope(0):
     88     with utils.keras_option_scope(save_traces):
---> 89       saved_nodes, node_paths = save_lib.save_and_return_nodes(
     90           model, filepath, signatures, options)
     91 
~/tf2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/save.py in save_and_return_nodes(obj, export_dir, signatures, options, raise_metadata_warning, experimental_skip_checkpoint)
   1101 
   1102   _, exported_graph, object_saver, asset_info, saved_nodes, node_paths = (
-> 1103       _build_meta_graph(obj, signatures, options, meta_graph_def,
   1104                         raise_metadata_warning))
   1105   saved_model.saved_model_schema_version = constants.SAVED_MODEL_SCHEMA_VERSION
~/tf2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/save.py in _build_meta_graph(obj, signatures, options, meta_graph_def, raise_metadata_warning)
   1288 
   1289   with save_context.save_context(options):
-> 1290     return _build_meta_graph_impl(obj, signatures, options, meta_graph_def,
   1291                                   raise_metadata_warning)
~/tf2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/save.py in _build_meta_graph_impl(obj, signatures, options, meta_graph_def, raise_metadata_warning)
   1205   checkpoint_graph_view = _AugmentedGraphView(obj)
   1206   if signatures is None:
-> 1207     signatures = signature_serialization.find_function_to_export(
   1208         checkpoint_graph_view)
   1209 
~/tf2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/signature_serialization.py in find_function_to_export(saveable_view)
     97   # If the user did not specify signatures, check the root object for a function
     98   # that can be made into a signature.
---> 99   functions = saveable_view.list_functions(saveable_view.root)
    100   signature = functions.get(DEFAULT_SIGNATURE_ATTR, None)
    101   if signature is not None:
~/tf2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/save.py in list_functions(self, obj)
    152     obj_functions = self._functions.get(obj, None)
    153     if obj_functions is None:
--> 154       obj_functions = obj._list_functions_for_serialization(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    155           self._serialization_cache)
    156       self._functions[obj] = obj_functions
~/tf2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in _list_functions_for_serialization(self, serialization_cache)
   2711     self.test_function = None
   2712     self.predict_function = None
-> 2713     functions = super(
   2714         Model, self)._list_functions_for_serialization(serialization_cache)
   2715     self.train_function = train_function
~/tf2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py in _list_functions_for_serialization(self, serialization_cache)
   3014 
   3015   def _list_functions_for_serialization(self, serialization_cache):
-> 3016     return (self._trackable_saved_model_saver
   3017             .list_functions_for_serialization(serialization_cache))
   3018 
~/tf2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/base_serialization.py in list_functions_for_serialization(self, serialization_cache)
     90       return {}
     91 
---> 92     fns = self.functions_to_serialize(serialization_cache)
     93 
     94     # The parent AutoTrackable class saves all user-defined tf.functions, and
~/tf2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/layer_serialization.py in functions_to_serialize(self, serialization_cache)
     71 
     72   def functions_to_serialize(self, serialization_cache):
---> 73     return (self._get_serialized_attributes(
     74         serialization_cache).functions_to_serialize)
     75 
~/tf2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/layer_serialization.py in _get_serialized_attributes(self, serialization_cache)
     87       return serialized_attr
     88 
---> 89     object_dict, function_dict = self._get_serialized_attributes_internal(
     90         serialization_cache)
     91 
~/tf2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/model_serialization.py in _get_serialized_attributes_internal(self, serialization_cache)
     51     # the ones serialized by Layer.
     52     objects, functions = (
---> 53         super(ModelSavedModelSaver, self)._get_serialized_attributes_internal(
     54             serialization_cache))
     55     functions['_default_save_signature'] = default_signature
~/tf2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/layer_serialization.py in _get_serialized_attributes_internal(self, serialization_cache)
     97     """Returns dictionary of serialized attributes."""
     98     objects = save_impl.wrap_layer_objects(self.obj, serialization_cache)
---> 99     functions = save_impl.wrap_layer_functions(self.obj, serialization_cache)
    100     # Attribute validator requires that the default save signature is added to
    101     # function dict, even if the value is None.
~/tf2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/save_impl.py in wrap_layer_functions(layer, serialization_cache)
    202           if isinstance(fn, LayerCall):
    203             fn = fn.wrapped_call
--> 204           fn.get_concrete_function()
    205 
    206   # Restore overwritten functions and losses
/usr/lib/python3.8/contextlib.py in __exit__(self, type, value, traceback)
    118         if type is None:
    119             try:
--> 120                 next(self.gen)
    121             except StopIteration:
    122                 return False
~/tf2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/save_impl.py in tracing_scope()
    365       if training is not None:
    366         with K.deprecated_internal_learning_phase_scope(training):
--> 367           fn.get_concrete_function(*args, **kwargs)
    368       else:
    369         fn.get_concrete_function(*args, **kwargs)
~/tf2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in get_concrete_function(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1365       ValueError: if this object has not yet been called on concrete values.
   1366     """
-> 1367     concrete = self._get_concrete_function_garbage_collected(*args, **kwargs)
   1368     concrete._garbage_collector.release()  # pylint: disable=protected-access
   1369     return concrete
~/tf2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in _get_concrete_function_garbage_collected(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1282       # In this case we have not created variables on the first call. So we can
   1283       # run the first trace but we should fail if variables are created.
-> 1284       concrete = self._stateful_fn._get_concrete_function_garbage_collected(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
   1285           *args, **kwargs)
   1286       if self._created_variables:
~/tf2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _get_concrete_function_garbage_collected(self, *args, **kwargs)
   3098       args, kwargs = None, None
   3099     with self._lock:
-> 3100       graph_function, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
   3101       seen_names = set()
   3102       captured = object_identity.ObjectIdentitySet(
~/tf2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _maybe_define_function(self, args, kwargs)
   3442 
   3443           self._function_cache.missed.add(call_context_key)
-> 3444           graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
   3445           self._function_cache.primary[cache_key] = graph_function
   3446 
~/tf2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _create_graph_function(self, args, kwargs, override_flat_arg_shapes)
   3277     arg_names = base_arg_names + missing_arg_names
   3278     graph_function = ConcreteFunction(
-> 3279         func_graph_module.func_graph_from_py_func(
   3280             self._name,
   3281             self._python_function,
~/tf2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in func_graph_from_py_func(name, python_func, args, kwargs, signature, func_graph, autograph, autograph_options, add_control_dependencies, arg_names, op_return_value, collections, capture_by_value, override_flat_arg_shapes)
    997         _, original_func = tf_decorator.unwrap(python_func)
    998 
--> 999       func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
   1000 
   1001       # invariant: `func_outputs` contains only Tensors, CompositeTensors,
~/tf2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in wrapped_fn(*args, **kwds)
    670         # the function a weak reference to itself to avoid a reference cycle.
    671         with OptionalXlaContext(compile_with_xla):
--> 672           out = weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
    673         return out
    674 
~/tf2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/save_impl.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    597       with autocast_variable.enable_auto_cast_variables(
    598           layer._compute_dtype_object):  # pylint: disable=protected-access
--> 599         ret = method(*args, **kwargs)
    600     _restore_layer_losses(original_losses)
    601     return ret
~/tf2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/utils.py in wrap_with_training_arg(*args, **kwargs)
    163       return wrapped_call(*args, **kwargs)
    164 
--> 165     return control_flow_util.smart_cond(
    166         training, lambda: replace_training_and_call(True),
    167         lambda: replace_training_and_call(False))
~/tf2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/control_flow_util.py in smart_cond(pred, true_fn, false_fn, name)
    107     return control_flow_ops.cond(
    108         pred, true_fn=true_fn, false_fn=false_fn, name=name)
--> 109   return smart_module.smart_cond(
    110       pred, true_fn=true_fn, false_fn=false_fn, name=name)
    111 
~/tf2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/smart_cond.py in smart_cond(pred, true_fn, false_fn, name)
     52   if pred_value is not None:
     53     if pred_value:
---> 54       return true_fn()
     55     else:
     56       return false_fn()
~/tf2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/utils.py in <lambda>()
    164 
    165     return control_flow_util.smart_cond(
--> 166         training, lambda: replace_training_and_call(True),
    167         lambda: replace_training_and_call(False))
    168 
~/tf2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/utils.py in replace_training_and_call(training)
    161     def replace_training_and_call(training):
    162       set_training_arg(training, training_arg_index, args, kwargs)
--> 163       return wrapped_call(*args, **kwargs)
    164 
    165     return control_flow_util.smart_cond(
~/tf2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/save_impl.py in call(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    679     return layer.keras_api.__call__  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    680   def call(inputs, *args, **kwargs):
--> 681     return call_and_return_conditional_losses(inputs, *args, **kwargs)[0]
    682   return _create_call_fn_decorator(layer, call)
    683 
~/tf2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/save_impl.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    637   def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    638     self._maybe_trace(args, kwargs)
--> 639     return self.wrapped_call(*args, **kwargs)
    640 
    641   def get_concrete_function(self, *args, **kwargs):
~/tf2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    887 
    888       with OptionalXlaContext(self._jit_compile):
--> 889         result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
    890 
    891       new_tracing_count = self.experimental_get_tracing_count()
~/tf2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
    922       # In this case we have not created variables on the first call. So we can
    923       # run the first trace but we should fail if variables are created.
--> 924       results = self._stateful_fn(*args, **kwds)
    925       if self._created_variables:
    926         raise ValueError("Creating variables on a non-first call to a function"
~/tf2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
   3020     with self._lock:
   3021       (graph_function,
-> 3022        filtered_flat_args) = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
   3023     return graph_function._call_flat(
   3024         filtered_flat_args, captured_inputs=graph_function.captured_inputs)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
~/tf2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _maybe_define_function(self, args, kwargs)
   3442 
   3443           self._function_cache.missed.add(call_context_key)
-> 3444           graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
   3445           self._function_cache.primary[cache_key] = graph_function
   3446 
~/tf2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _create_graph_function(self, args, kwargs, override_flat_arg_shapes)
   3277     arg_names = base_arg_names + missing_arg_names
   3278     graph_function = ConcreteFunction(
-> 3279         func_graph_module.func_graph_from_py_func(
   3280             self._name,
   3281             self._python_function,
~/tf2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in func_graph_from_py_func(name, python_func, args, kwargs, signature, func_graph, autograph, autograph_options, add_control_dependencies, arg_names, op_return_value, collections, capture_by_value, override_flat_arg_shapes)
    997         _, original_func = tf_decorator.unwrap(python_func)
    998 
--> 999       func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
   1000 
   1001       # invariant: `func_outputs` contains only Tensors, CompositeTensors,
~/tf2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in wrapped_fn(*args, **kwds)
    670         # the function a weak reference to itself to avoid a reference cycle.
    671         with OptionalXlaContext(compile_with_xla):
--> 672           out = weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
    673         return out
    674 
~/tf2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/save_impl.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    597       with autocast_variable.enable_auto_cast_variables(
    598           layer._compute_dtype_object):  # pylint: disable=protected-access
--> 599         ret = method(*args, **kwargs)
    600     _restore_layer_losses(original_losses)
    601     return ret
~/tf2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/utils.py in wrap_with_training_arg(*args, **kwargs)
    163       return wrapped_call(*args, **kwargs)
    164 
--> 165     return control_flow_util.smart_cond(
    166         training, lambda: replace_training_and_call(True),
    167         lambda: replace_training_and_call(False))
~/tf2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/control_flow_util.py in smart_cond(pred, true_fn, false_fn, name)
    107     return control_flow_ops.cond(
    108         pred, true_fn=true_fn, false_fn=false_fn, name=name)
--> 109   return smart_module.smart_cond(
    110       pred, true_fn=true_fn, false_fn=false_fn, name=name)
    111 
~/tf2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/smart_cond.py in smart_cond(pred, true_fn, false_fn, name)
     52   if pred_value is not None:
     53     if pred_value:
---> 54       return true_fn()
     55     else:
     56       return false_fn()
~/tf2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/utils.py in <lambda>()
    164 
    165     return control_flow_util.smart_cond(
--> 166         training, lambda: replace_training_and_call(True),
    167         lambda: replace_training_and_call(False))
    168 
~/tf2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/utils.py in replace_training_and_call(training)
    161     def replace_training_and_call(training):
    162       set_training_arg(training, training_arg_index, args, kwargs)
--> 163       return wrapped_call(*args, **kwargs)
    164 
    165     return control_flow_util.smart_cond(
~/tf2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/save_impl.py in call_and_return_conditional_losses(*args, **kwargs)
    661   def call_and_return_conditional_losses(*args, **kwargs):
    662     """Returns layer (call_output, conditional losses) tuple."""
--> 663     call_output = layer_call(*args, **kwargs)
    664     if version_utils.is_v1_layer_or_model(layer):
    665       conditional_losses = layer.get_losses_for(
~/tf2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/sequential.py in call(self, inputs, training, mask)
    378       if not self.built:
    379         self._init_graph_network(self.inputs, self.outputs)
--> 380       return super(Sequential, self).call(inputs, training=training, mask=mask)
    381 
    382     outputs = inputs  # handle the corner case where self.layers is empty
~/tf2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/functional.py in call(self, inputs, training, mask)
    418         a list of tensors if there are more than one outputs.
    419     """
--> 420     return self._run_internal_graph(
    421         inputs, training=training, mask=mask)
    422 
~/tf2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/functional.py in _run_internal_graph(self, inputs, training, mask)
    554 
    555         args, kwargs = node.map_arguments(tensor_dict)
--> 556         outputs = node.layer(*args, **kwargs)
    557 
    558         # Update tensor_dict.
~/tf2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow_probability/python/layers/distribution_layer.py in __call__(self, inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    228   def __call__(self, inputs, *args, **kwargs):
    229     self._enter_dunder_call = True
--> 230     distribution, _ = super(DistributionLambda, self).__call__(
    231         inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    232     self._enter_dunder_call = False
~/tf2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in __iter__(self)
    518   def __iter__(self):
    519     if not context.executing_eagerly():
--> 520       self._disallow_iteration()
    521 
    522     shape = self._shape_tuple()
~/tf2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in _disallow_iteration(self)
    511       self._disallow_when_autograph_disabled("iterating over `tf.Tensor`")
    512     elif ag_ctx.control_status_ctx().status == ag_ctx.Status.ENABLED:
--> 513       self._disallow_when_autograph_enabled("iterating over `tf.Tensor`")
    514     else:
    515       # Default: V1-style Graph execution.
~/tf2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in _disallow_when_autograph_enabled(self, task)
    487 
    488   def _disallow_when_autograph_enabled(self, task):
--> 489     raise errors.OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError(
    490         "{} is not allowed: AutoGraph did convert this function. This might"
    491         " indicate you are trying to use an unsupported feature.".format(task))
OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: iterating over `tf.Tensor` is not allowed: AutoGraph did convert this function. This might indicate you are trying to use an unsupported feature.*_
```

**Workaround works with limited capability** as shown in https://github.com/tensorflow/probability/issues/325#issuecomment-477213850
But this only saves the weights and not other details of the model.

**Workaround works with h5 format**
h5 format saving works, but cannot load the model

```
loaded_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('/tmp/model/probabilistic_model.h5')
```

Error while using h5 format for saving and then loading the model is shown below.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_11377/686337657.py in <module>
----> 1 loaded_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('/tmp/model/probabilistic_model.h5')

~/tf2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/save.py in load_model(filepath, custom_objects, compile, options)
    199         if (h5py is not None and
    200             (isinstance(filepath, h5py.File) or h5py.is_hdf5(filepath))):
--> 201           return hdf5_format.load_model_from_hdf5(filepath, custom_objects,
    202                                                   compile)
    203 

~/tf2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/hdf5_format.py in load_model_from_hdf5(filepath, custom_objects, compile)
    178       model_config = model_config.decode('utf-8')
    179     model_config = json_utils.decode(model_config)
--> 180     model = model_config_lib.model_from_config(model_config,
    181                                                custom_objects=custom_objects)
    182 

~/tf2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/model_config.py in model_from_config(config, custom_objects)
     57                     '`Sequential.from_config(config)`?')
     58   from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import deserialize  # pylint: disable=g-import-not-at-top
---> 59   return deserialize(config, custom_objects=custom_objects)
     60 
     61 

~/tf2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/serialization.py in deserialize(config, custom_objects)
    157   """
    158   populate_deserializable_objects()
--> 159   return generic_utils.deserialize_keras_object(
    160       config,
    161       module_objects=LOCAL.ALL_OBJECTS,

~/tf2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/generic_utils.py in deserialize_keras_object(identifier, module_objects, custom_objects, printable_module_name)
    666 
    667       if 'custom_objects' in arg_spec.args:
--> 668         deserialized_obj = cls.from_config(
    669             cls_config,
    670             custom_objects=dict(

~/tf2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/sequential.py in from_config(cls, config, custom_objects)
    495     model = cls(name=name)
    496     for layer_config in layer_configs:
--> 497       layer = layer_module.deserialize(layer_config,
    498                                        custom_objects=custom_objects)
    499       model.add(layer)

~/tf2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/serialization.py in deserialize(config, custom_objects)
    157   """
    158   populate_deserializable_objects()
--> 159   return generic_utils.deserialize_keras_object(
    160       config,
    161       module_objects=LOCAL.ALL_OBJECTS,

~/tf2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/generic_utils.py in deserialize_keras_object(identifier, module_objects, custom_objects, printable_module_name)
    651     # In this case we are dealing with a Keras config dictionary.
    652     config = identifier
--> 653     (cls, cls_config) = class_and_config_for_serialized_keras_object(
    654         config, module_objects, custom_objects, printable_module_name)
    655 

~/tf2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/generic_utils.py in class_and_config_for_serialized_keras_object(config, module_objects, custom_objects, printable_module_name)
    554   cls = get_registered_object(class_name, custom_objects, module_objects)
    555   if cls is None:
--> 556     raise ValueError(enter code here
    557         'Unknown {}: {}. Please ensure this object is '
    558         'passed to the `custom_objects` argument. See '

ValueError: Unknown layer: OneHotCategorical. Please ensure this object is passed to the `custom_objects` argument. See https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/save_and_serialize#registering_the_custom_object for details.
```

**Describe the expected behavior**
Saves a probabilistic_model as a TensorFlow SavedModel

Answer (score 1):

```
custom_objects = {"OneHotCategorical": tfp.layers.OneHotCategorical}
with tf.keras.utils.custom_object_scope(custom_objects):
    restored_model = tf.keras.models.load_model(saved_path)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, and thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to to include an explanation of your code? That will help future readers better understand what is going on, and especially those members of the community who are new to the language and struggling to understand the concepts.